# Perform get request from within Jquery after an anchor tag is clicked

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to perform a GET request from within JQuery after an anchor tag is clicked but the code seems not to be working

```
<a href="/getData" class="getData">Get started</a>  //HTML code for the element
```

Below is the JQuery code i wrote to make the GET request once the above has been clicked, then push obtained data into another element

```js
$(".getData").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = "/getData"
  $.get(href, function(data) {
    $(".data-section").html(data)
  })
})
```

I am not getting any error message but the request is not been sent as well

Comment: Code seems fine. Can you debug it by giving a console within click function (before AJAX Get) and check whether the click event occurs.

Comment: Thanks @FaizulHassan You are right, the click event is not even performed. Any idea what may be the issue?

Comment: Please check if jQuery plugin is present in the application. If yes then wrap the above code within dom ready function..

**$(function() {
    // Code here
});**

Comment: That works @FaizulHassan After wrapping the code with the DOM ready function, i had to switch my jQuery to a non-slim updated package

Comment: I'm glad that it worked.. Cheers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wrap the wrap the code with the DOM ready function and switch my jQuery to a non-slim updated package

```js
$(function() {
  $(".getData").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const href = "/getData"
    $.get(href, function(data) {
      $(".data-section").html(data)
    });
  });
});
```